# Incorrect result after subtracting 2 dates in php

Tags: php

```
$todays_date     =  date('d-m-y');  //17-2-18
$return_date     =  "16-02-18"; //day-month-year
$todays_datesec  =  strtotime($todays_date);
$return_datesec  =  strtotime($return_date);
$diff            =  $todays_datesec - $return_datesec;
$days            =  $diff/86400; 
echo $days
```

The above code is displaying a value of -363 which is incorrect.The anser should be 1,Please help.

Comment: have you tried changing date format of $daysleft ?

Comment: Make your date formats unambiguous..... with a format like `"17-02-18";`, is that 17th of February 2018, or 18th of February 2017? You're asking PHP To guess what you meant, and complaining when it guesses wrong.... if I asked you to tell me what date `5/7/12` was, could you (as a human being with intelligence) tell me the date I'm thinking of?

Comment: Is your question actually about the `date` function? That's what your last sentence implies, but that function isn't mentioned in the code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Also you should be using `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: Using a proper class for this would also skip over the issue that there are 86400 seconds in a day, not 84000

Comment: thank you guys fixed it.The problem was with the date formatting. i changed the dates from 17-02-18 & 16-02-18 to 17-02-2018 & 16-02-2018 , php had problem subracting when the year was in the form '18'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$return_date="16-02-18";
```

is not a correct date format for `strtotime()`, if you try this:

```
$return_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($return_date));
```

you will get `18-02-2016`, and it's not a correct date

If you can't change the input data format, maybe you can modify it first by string operation, like this:

```
$return_date = substr_replace($return_date , '20', strlen($return_date)-2, 0);
```

I assume you only handle dates above 2000

Answer (score 1):

The date format you given is not supported by [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) function. Use php [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)  to make date from `m-d-y` format.

In you example it would be

```
17-02-18
|  |  |___Year
|  |___Month
|___Date
```

Example code

```
$todays_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '17-02-18');
$return_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '16-02-18');
$diff = $return_date->diff($todays_date);
echo "Days :".$diff->days;
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/957926)

Only one format is support which is `dd.mm.yy` in [date](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) so you can use your code like below

```
$todays_date="17.02.18";
$return_date="13.02.18";
$returnsecs=strtotime($return_date);
$todayssecs=strtotime($todays_date);
$daysleft= $todayssecs - $returnsecs;
$r = (int)($daysleft/3600);
echo "Result : ".$r;
```

[Demo of above code]https://eval.in/957940

Comment: @AdiLIsmaiL : what method you are using to fix this ?

Comment: When i specified the date as 17-2-2018 and 13-02-2018 the answer was correct.The problem was with the format of the date that is 17-2-18 & 13-2-18

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$todayDate = date('d-m-Y');
echo $todayDate;
```

Output:

```
17-02-2018
```

If you put 'Y', the year will be displayed with 4 digits, if you use 'y' the year will be with 2 digits.

You can take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php)!